# Why is the produced assembly not equivalent between returning by reference and copy when inlined?

Tags: rust

I have a small struct:

```
pub struct Foo {
    pub a: i32,
    pub b: i32,
    pub c: i32,
}
```

I was using pairs of the fields in the form `(a,b) (b,c) (c,a)`. To avoid duplication of the code, I created a utility function which would allow me to iterate over the pairs:

```
fn get_foo_ref(&self) -> [(&i32, &i32); 3] {
    [(&self.a, &self.b), (&self.b, &self.c), (&self.c, &self.a)]
}
```

I had to decide if I should return the values as references or copy the `i32`. Later on, I plan to switch to a non-`Copy` type instead of an `i32`, so I decided to use references. I expected the resulting code should be equivalent since everything would be inlined.

I am generally optimistic about optimizations, so I suspected that the code would be equivalent when using this function as compared to hand written code examples.

First the variant using the function:

```
pub fn testing_ref(f: Foo) -> i32 {
    let mut sum = 0;

    for i in 0..3 {
        let (l, r) = f.get_foo_ref()[i];

        sum += *l + *r;
    }

    sum
}
```

Then the *hand-written* variant:

```
pub fn testing_direct(f: Foo) -> i32 {
    let mut sum = 0;

    sum += f.a + f.b;
    sum += f.b + f.c;
    sum += f.c + f.a;

    sum
}
```

To my disappointment, all 3 methods resulted in different assembly code. The worst code was generated for the case with references, and the best code was the one that didn't use my utility function at all. Why is that? Shouldn't the compiler generate equivalent code in this case?

You can view the [resulting assembly code on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/3tNxVx); I also have the 'equivalent' [assembly code from C++](https://godbolt.org/g/SaB7gt).

In C++, the compiler generated equivalent code between `get_foo` and `get_foo_ref`, although I don't understand why the code for all 3 cases is not equivalent.

Why did the compiler did not generate equivalent code for all 3 cases?

**Update**:

I've modified slightly code to use arrays and to add one more *direct* case.
[Rust version with f64 and arrays](https://godbolt.org/g/52S4sV)
[C++ version with f64 and arrays](https://godbolt.org/g/HqnXGn)
This time the generated code between in C++ is exactly the same. However the Rust' assembly differs, and returning by references results in worse assembly.

Well, I guess this is another example that nothing can be taken for granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Microbenchmarks are trickery, instruction count does not directly translate into high/low performance.

---

> Later on, I plan to switch to a non-Copy type instead of an i32, so I decided to use references.

Then, you should check the generated assembly for your new type.

In your optimized example, the compiler is being very crafty:

> ```
> pub fn testing_direct(f: Foo) -> i32 {
>     let mut sum = 0;
>
>     sum += f.a + f.b;
>     sum += f.b + f.c;
>     sum += f.c + f.a;
>
>     sum
> }
> ```

Yields:

> ```
> example::testing_direct:
>         push    rbp
>         mov     rbp, rsp
>         mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
>         add     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
>         add     eax, dword ptr [rdi + 8]
>         add     eax, eax
>         pop     rbp
>         ret
> ```

Which is roughly `sum += f.a; sum += f.b; sum += f.c; sum += sum;`.

That is, the compiler realized that:

1. `f.X` was added twice
2. `f.X * 2` was equivalent to adding it twice

While the former may be inhibited in the other cases by the use of indirection, the latter is *VERY* specific to `i32` (and addition being commutative).

For example, switching your code to `f32` (still `Copy`, but addition is not longer commutative), I get the very same assembly for both `testing_direct` and `testing` (and slightly different for `testing_ref`):

> ```
> example::testing:
>         push    rbp
>         mov     rbp, rsp
>         movss   xmm1, dword ptr [rdi]
>         movss   xmm2, dword ptr [rdi + 4]
>         movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rdi + 8]
>         movaps  xmm3, xmm1
>         addss   xmm3, xmm2
>         xorps   xmm4, xmm4
>         addss   xmm4, xmm3
>         addss   xmm2, xmm0
>         addss   xmm2, xmm4
>         addss   xmm0, xmm1
>         addss   xmm0, xmm2
>         pop     rbp
>         ret
> ```

And there's no trickery any longer.

So it's really not possible to infer much from your example, check with the real type.

Comment: Well, this does not really answer my question, Maybe the note about target types was unnecessary. I will accept your answer since now my question really probably has no good answer. I should've formatted my question more towards why the assembly is not equivalent between these cases for i32.

Comment: I guess the question isn't about which version is more efficient, but about why there is *any* difference between the value and reference based versions, given that the compiler "sees" all relevant definitions and can inline the functions. An answer to that question would likely involving the details of the particular version of rustc and llvm.